# sqlite DELETE WHERE... not working - python sqlite

Tags: python, windows, sqlite

I am new to sqlite and tried to create a simple table, but once I try to delete values in it (with the delete() function), it doesn't output any errors, but when I see the values using show(), nothing changes.

Here is my code:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('Test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def create(name, args):
    c.execute(f'''CREATE TABLE {name}
{args}''')

def show(filtercheck=False, item=None):
    if filtercheck == False:
        for row in c.execute("SELECT * FROM People"):
            print(row)
    else:
        if item != None:
            for row in c.execute(f"SELECT * FROM People ORDER BY {item}"):
                print(row)

def add(data):
    c.execute(f"insert into People values {data}")
    conn.commit()

def delete(Value):
    c.execute("DELETE FROM People WHERE 'Name'=(?)", (Value,))
    conn.commit()

def save():
    conn.commit()

def close():
    conn.close()


#create("People", ("Name text", "phoneno int
#add(('test', 12345678))
save()
show()
delete('test')
```

I have tried researching online, but couldn't get an answer to this.

Thank you

Comment: Remove the single quotes around Name: `"DELETE FROM People WHERE Name=(?)"`

Comment: It gave me `column not found: Name`, so I tried running `[d[0] for d in c.description]` to see if the column names were the problem, but it returns `['Name text', 'phoneno int']` when the quotes are around name. When I remove them, and try the delete() before, it returns  `'NoneType' object is not iterable`, like if the delete() was somehow eliminating the columns, but the data is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to quote your identifier with " instead of ' - also drop the parens as you don't need them:

```
DELETE FROM People WHERE "Name"=?
```

or

```
DELETE FROM People WHERE `Name`=?
```

or

```
DELETE FROM People WHERE [Name]=?
```

The SQLite docs say not to use `'`:

> (second bullet) If a keyword in single quotes (ex: 'key' or 'glob') is used in a context where an identifier is allowed but where a string literal is not allowed, then the token is understood to be an identifier instead of a string literal.
>
> Programmers are cautioned not to use the two exceptions described in the previous bullets. We emphasize that they exist only so that old and ill-formed SQL statements will run correctly. Future versions of SQLite might raise errors instead of accepting the malformed statements covered by the exceptions above.

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: Somehow, it still didn't work for me, but this is what im getting on the shell: ```show() - ('test', 12345678)
('test', 12345678) - delete() - ('test', 12345678)
('test', 12345678)```

Comment: Pretty sure it has to do with WHERE, because I tried the SELECT argument, but had the same issue: ```for r in c.execute("SELECT * FROM People WHERE 'Name'=?", ('test',)):
                                                                                                                           
                                ...print(r)

```  There was no output